# Magento - Free shipping as default option

Tags: magento

We are using two shipping options. If under $50 than add $4.95 and free shipping when more than $50. Magento is only using the $4.95 also when the cart total amount it over $50. How to set the free shipping method as default?

as you can see there is also no option in our template to select the shipping method.

[image: magento cart]

Comment: Through admin you can try to edit settings of shipping method position.

Comment: I think this helped me: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17806/free-shipping-if-subtotal-greater-than-or-equal-50 but I am not sure if it is the best option.

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to enable two shipping method from admin panel.

1. Enable Free Shipping and Set Minimum Order Amount to $50
2. Enable Flat Rate Shipping method and set Price to 4.95

By this way Flat Rate shipping method always visible in the checkout and Free shipping method come when Order amount is minimum $50.

As when Free shipping method enable, we need to remove Flat Rate shipping method. For this you need to follow this process:

Copy `Flatrate Carrier Model` From `Core` pool to `local` pool.

**From:** `app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Flatrate.php`

**To:** `app/code/local/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Flatrate.php`

In the `collectRates` function add the below lines:

```
if ($request->getBaseSubtotalInclTax() >= Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/freeshipping/free_shipping_subtotal')) {
        return false;
    }
```

After these lines:

```
if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the admin set your Shipping Method Rate to default 4.95 and in your shipping model (e.g Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Flatrate) method collectRates, add a condition to check for the cart total:

```
if ($request->getBaseSubtotalInclTax() >= 50)
{
    $method->setPrice(0.00);
    $method->setCost(0.00);
    $method->setCarrierTitle('Free Shipping');  
}
```